# Recompose VM using vmware 5.5 power cli

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vsphere, powercli

How can I recompose a VM v1 with existing parent VM v2's snapshot s2 ?
After referring few documents, I saw command **Send-LinkedCloneRecompose** for recomposing VM.

I am trying this command as follows:

```
$myVM = 'v1'
$clone = Get-DesktopVM -Name $myVM
$pool = Get-Pool -pool_id $clone.pool_id
$date = Get-Date
$date = $date.AddSeconds(10)
Write-Host "Recomposing" $clone.name 
Send-LinkedCloneRecompose -machine_id $clone.machine_id -parentVMPath $pool.parentVMPath -parentSnapshotPath $pool.parentVMSnapshotPath -schedule $date -forcelogoff $true |  tee-object -variable vmState
```

Here I am getting error as *Get-DesktopVM : The term 'Get-DesktopVM' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.*

I am getting the same error for powercli commandlets **Get-Pool** and **Send-LinkedCloneRecompose** as well.

I am using VMware VSphere power cli 5.5 release 2 patch 1.

Can anyone please help me in understanding the problem here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed to add 
    ***& "C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware View\Server\extras\PowerShell\add-snapin.ps1"*** 
before executing above commands. So the commandlets were not recognized.